# Balancing via Logistic Regression

Tags: python, regression

I have a question about logistic regression. For my thesis I have to compare companies using different financial ratios using Python. The financial ratios should be balanced either by logistic regression or probit regression. I have already looked at some tutorials and these have worked with explanatory and dependent variables, but there are no dependent variables in my data set. I only need the regression to balance the different financial ratios and not to explain dependent variables. The goal is to calculate a score ("Propensity Score") for each company, from which I can then calculate the distance to the "nearest" company and thus get a proxy for comparability with other companies.

Unfortunately, I completely lack the approach here and I can't find any instructions or examples. Does anyone of you have an idea how I can proceed here? I hope my problem becomes clear.

Comment: I don't think that you understand what you are saying which makes the problem hard to comprehend. Logistic (and probit) regressions are supervised ML models which means that they require dependent variable. If you don't have dependent variable, you can't use any supervised model. Or in other words, you need an unsupervised model and that is a completely different story (and I don't think that it is what you are looking for either)

Comment: Yeah going with @MatusDubrava here. You can't use regression models without a dependent variable (supervised), which leaves you with a unsupervised dataset. Try looking into K-NN, K-Means, SVM's, and any other unsupervised models.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like regression models are not the right approach here. If I understand correctly and you want to find companies which are comparable based on different financial ratios you should use clustering algorithm like k-means or just just use a distance metric like euclidean distance to find the closest neighbor for each company.